# Wrong height of div with img tag inside

Tags: image, css, html, height

I have a div with an image tag inside, and the div height appears to be a little larger than the image.

I could fix this problem by setting a specific height for the div (the same as the image), but I'm working with a responsive layout, and I don't want to set a specific height for the div, so that when the browser window scales (for example in mobile devices) the div will scale and maintain the ratio.

I need that the div height to be exactly as the image height.

This is the scenario:

`<div class='box'><img src='image.jpg'></div>`

Css is:

`img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto;
}`

Does anybody know how to fix this problem?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 39):

The problem is that the image's natural styling gives it a little bit of margin on the bottom making it ugly to say the least. An easy fix is to just display: block, float: left on the image and the space should go away.

either that or you can play around w/ the border-collapsing on the image if you really don't want to float it. However, that's a solution that would probably cause more problems in the end.

so it's going to end up being something like

```
.box img {
  display: block; /*inline block would be fine too*/
  float: left;
}
```

hope that helps.

Comment: great! it works with display:block only! Thank you very much.

Comment: img add "display:block" solve it ! 
And the actual reason is that img has default css "vertical-align: baseline". so we can also solve it with add "vertical-align: top" to img.

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to determine the vertical alignment of the image.

```
img {
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/xozatu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 6):

use img: block. that's all....

Answer (score 2):

To have the `div` be the same element as its child `img` element:

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
}

div img {
    margin: 0;
}
```

I'd suggest, though, that you use a `span` instead of a `div` (that way it'll automatically 'collapse' its width to that of its contents:

```
span {
    padding: 0;
}
span img {
    margin: 0;
}
```

[JS Fiddle proof-of-concept (for both)](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ZB3QD/).

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about just setting the size of the Div ?
In css:

```
.box
{
 height: 10px;
 width:10px;
}
```

You can also not set the image in your code but set the "box's" DIV background image to that image instead:

```
.box
{
 height: 10px;
 width:10px;
 background:url('/imgURL/filename.gif') white no-repeat;
}
```

(10px is just a random number ofcourse. Set it to whatever size you need)

Comment: I working on a responsive layout, so I whouldn't set a specifi height for the div; so that when the browser window is resized, the div scales.

Answer (score 0):

The simple modern solution that works is as follows

```
div {
    display: flex;
}
```