# div containing another div and an image getting unexpected height

Tags: html, css

Here, the div *definition* is supposed to get the same height as the image's. but i'm getting and additional 4 pixels for the height. do anyone have an idea why this is happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="29.jpg" />
        <div class="definition">
            DEFINITION GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>

body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
}

.definition {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
}

    .definition:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 2s ease-in;
    }
```

Comment: One thing that often messes up layouts is just _whitespaces_ between tags. Try removing all unnecessary whitespaces inside `container`.

Comment: If pietu1998's solution is not working, put a jsfiddle, it may help.

Comment: u mean non-breaking space or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by default img tag margin.

add to css

```
.container img { display:block; float:left; }
```

please see this solution. =>
[Wrong height of div with img tag inside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656570/wrong-height-of-div-with-img-tag-inside)

Comment: why'd u use float: left there?

Answer (score 2):

Include a CSS reset . It may be a browser problem .

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine. All you need to do is put the css codes under

```
<style>

your codes

</style>
```

I have Replaced your img  with the following link. It is also an image.

```
<img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/06/14/8571472/ingredients_icon-kerned.jpg" />
```

It is displayed with its original size.

Full Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
}

html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.container {
    position: absolute;
}

.definition {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: red;
    opacity: 0;
}

    .definition:hover {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: 2s ease-in;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <img src="http://ww1.prweb.com/prfiles/2011/06/14/8571472/ingredients_icon-kerned.jpg" />
        <div class="definition">
            DEFINITION GOES HERE
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```