# Why is my right cell always getting a height of 196px?

Tags: html, css, html-email

The structure of my table is

```
                <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="404">
                            <img src="assets/Hero-Image2.png" width="404" height="192" style="width:404px;height:192px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="396" bgcolor="#00188F">
                            <h1 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Segoe,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16pt;font-weight:100; margin-bottom:10px;">Simpilfied IT management for any enterprise</h1>
                            <h2 style="color:#FFF;font-family:Segoe,Tahoma,Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14pt;font-weight:100;">Gain control over any hybrid cloud with our cost-effective all-in-one cloud solution</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

aand I want the image inside the first cell to have the same height as the second cell (so that the image blends into the background color of it. I know there are alternative ways of doing this, but I'm constrained since this is an HTML email for Outlook).

Right now the right cell is **always** having a height of `196px`, even if I strip its contents to nothing:

```
                <table  border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="404">
                            <img src="assets/Hero-Image2.png" width="404" height="192" style="width:404px;height:192px;border:0;margin:0;outline:0;"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="396" bgcolor="#00188F">

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

The right cell is  always 196px and this causes the left cell to be the same height. Makes no sense.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you add a `display: block` to the style of your image it will be fixed.

```html
<img src="//placehold.it/404x192" style="width:404px; height:192px; display: block" />
```

[The first answer should help you to understand why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10656570/wrong-height-of-div-with-img-tag-inside)

---

EDIT: Actually, you dont need nothing but the display block and the image sizes.

Answer (score 0):

What are the dimensions of your image?
I don't think HTML is "smart" enough to stretch your image to fit to your exact request.

Maybe you should try resizing your image in paint/photoshop to a dimension that has the same height/width ratio as 404:192 and see if that helps.